# How can I execute a runnable jar with external classpath?

Tags: java, linux, jar, classpath

I'm trying to run a `Runnable Jar` in `JAVA` with an external `jars` folder as its classpath on `Linux`.

```
java -cp "/path/to/jars/*" -jar app.jar
```

But I'm receiving `NoClassFound` exception for a class that in the jars folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "external classpath"? The classes should not be in app.jar? Or the classpath should not be specified by app.jar Manifest file?

Comment: Any update? We are 2019 now!

Answer (score 0):

Use full jar name in classpath. Like

```
java -classpath /java/MyClasses/myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool
```

if you have more than one jar, then append them to the classpath with 'OS' separator.

```
java -classpath /java/MyClasses:/java/OtherClasses ...
```